# How to build MVC on yii if i already have model, view and controller files?

Tags: php, yii, yii-components, framework-migration

Starting to learn yii, read some articles and most popular tutorials. Created 1st application using this one http://www.yiiframework.com/tour/ . Now I want to make real registration-authorization, have found very decent example which does contain model.php, view.php and controller.php, code seems clear to me. I also realise what does the 1st application structure mean, but I have no idea how can I implement this files that i found. Shall I use yiic some specific way? Please give me the idea what should I do to make it working?

Comment: `yiic webapp <appname>` will create a new app structure for you.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I will try to copy-past code into the files of already working test application firstly, then if it`s not gonna work will create a new one as soon as I don`t get any result.

Comment: If you already have the application and you want just to add the authentication/authorization and registration, then you do not need Yii. It would actually be harmful, because I honestly doubt that you designed it after Django (which is what influenced Yii).

Comment: Have a look at http://yiitutorials.net/ for some tutorials on using yiic and a few other basic Yii tutorials

Comment: I am working on some online-project, we just decided to try yii framework. Hope to handle it. Registration-authorization is just the 1st step, I know yiiframework.com contains some pretty simple tutorial about how to implement standart authorization, but there`s no registration and I need to make it by myself. Site which is link you shared with me is quite helpful as well, there are some good ones like url-rewriting tutorial, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The most common answer for this is to do the [blog tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/start.overview)
It covers every basic concept of Yii, after that you should understand how to implement the files you have found in your own application. 
Just read it carefully, not just try to fly over it, most of the time, if you're going the wrong way or don't understand something, it is because you have missed it in the tutorial.